# Get/Setting the Title for videos with C#

Tags: c#, video, id3, id3-tag

I've looked into a couple of libraries, and have only been able to find ID3 libraries for music files. I need a way to edit the "title" field of a couple common video titles. Does anybody have any experience with this and could give me a starting place?

If there's a way to implement an API for WMP to edit the library definition of the title for streaming, that would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what type of container files you're dealing with?  The method for doing this with ASF files, for example, is quite a bit different from MP4 files.  For ASF, you'd use the Windows Media Format SDK.  For MP4 files, a number of libraries exist.  I'd use mp4v2, personally.